# How to insert both an image and a button in an Android application at once?

Tags: android, image, switching

I need to insert two images and two buttons.  The action required is that when I click on the first button, the corresponding image should be displayed.  The same action is required for other button also, but the second image should be displayed.

Comment: Is it possible to expand your question to contain more detail??????? please

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you mean a button with an image on it?

For that, you'll need an [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html).

Comment: i need to insert  2 images and 2 buttons.action required is that whn i click on th first button corrsponding image should be displayed.same action required for other button also but second image shid be displayed.

Comment: So you want the image to be displayed after button click or the image should be a button?

Comment: there should always 2 buttons and an image.image switches according to the button

Answer (score 0):

Image button can be added as

```
<ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ImageButton01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon">
</ImageButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we finally understood what is required you need to have an onClick listener on both the buttons which when invoked will change the image you are displaying :-)